# Index formula with dynamic array reference

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

I have a table that is referencing a pivot table on the same sheet. I added a form control scroll bar to be able to flip through the data without changing the view.

The headers of that table are linked to the headers of the pivot table. I am trying to write the  =INDEX(L3:L$17,$D$6) formula so that the column info is adjusted automatically.

I managed to use the columnletter to convert the match of the header to the correct letter but don't know how to adjust the Index formula to use that info.

The goal is to change the index column array reference whenever I change the header dependency to another column.

[image]

change to Header from City to Street, should change the Index formula to use column M instead of L

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Match function will search the header word in the pivot table.
So you can change the words in the header and get the results for it without changing the formula.

```
   Option 1  E8=    =INDEX($L$3:$N$26;$F$3+ROWS($E$8:E8)-1;MATCH(Q$6;$L$2:$N$2;0))

Option 2  Q7=INDEX($L3:$N$26;$F$3;MATCH(Q$6;$L$2:$N$2;0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for lack of clarity. I want the index formula to change according to the column referred to in the header. So if the header (city) refers to column L, the index array is to capture L3:L17. If there would be a change in header dependent to e.g. column M, the formula is to update to M3:M17 without the user having to manually change the Index formula.

Comment: i added another picture to maybe better explain. If I would change the header from City to Street, the index formulas below, should automatically change from column L to M based on the columnletter match result.

Comment: @hbg i updated the answer. I think it is that you want